# Почему @cached_property каждый раз производит вычисления?

Tags: django

Есть модель, в её поле `geoposition` хранится `latitude` и `longitude`, в виде строки, в таком виде `'27.234234234,53.23423423434'`

Это поле предоставленно [django-geoposition](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition). Благодаря ему очень удобно вносить адресс.

Далее, но так как поле хранит долготу и широту, мне бы желательно хранить ещё и реальный адрес. Не знаю. правильно ли так делать, но я решил использовать [geocoder](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/). Так же, мне нужно хранить город и страну.

Я решил не выделять под эти значения поля, а решил хранить в `property`, а для того, чтобы минимизировать количество обращений к внешним ресурсам, решил использовать `cached_property`

```
class Address(models.Model):
    geoposition = GeopositionField(verbose_name=_('Адресс'),
        help_text='Введите полный адрес, вместе с городом')
    city = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.City', null=True, verbose_name='Город')
    country = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.Country',null=True, verbose_name='Страна')
    entrance = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Подъезд'), null=True, max_length=4, blank=True)
    floor = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Этаж'), null=True, max_length=4, blank=True)
    flat = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Квартира'), null=True, max_length=4, blank=True)

    @cached_property
    def address(self):
        g = geocoder.yandex([
            str(self.geoposition).split(',')[0], 
            str(self.geoposition).split(',')[1]
        ],
        method='reverse', lang='ru-RU')
        return g.address


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.address:
            self.address()

        super(Address, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Адреса"
        verbose_name_plural = "Адрес"

    def __str__(self):
        if self.address:
            return '%s' % str(self.address)
        return '%s' % str(self.pk)
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что при каждой попытке редактировать модель, которая связана с Address, я вижу, что происходит вычисление `property`, и даже в некоторых случаях ловлю `connection time out` от внешних сервисов.

Не понимаю, не верно использую сам `cached_property`, или же причиной является неверно написаный `save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в методе `save()` обращаетесь не к свойству `address`, а к методу `address()`, поэтому кэширования не происходит.

Comment: Благодарю!
Долго не мог разобраться...